# Find Row where two columns are minimum

Tags: r

I want to find the rows where for the first time value < 0.
I tried with grouping, but then of course the columns are independent

Data:

```
Date          Value      Name
2017-01-01    0          BlueCar
2017-01-02    4          BlueCar
2017-01-03    4          BlueCar
2017-01-04    0          BlueCar
2017-01-01    4          RedCar
2017-01-02    0          RedCar
2017-01-03    1          RedCar
```

Desired result:

```
Date          Value      Name
2017-01-01    0          BlueCar
2017-01-02    0          RedCar
```

Note that BlueCar has two rows with Value: 0. In my frame that happens a couple times. I want to find the row where that happens for the first time for every name

Update: Has to be robust against unordered Date. Of course you could order beforehand but - you know ;-) were lazy

Comment: Did you mean value <= 0 ?

Comment: When you say "first time", do you mean "the first record with Value <(=?) 0", or with the smallest `time` column? If the data is guaranteed to be in time order within Name groups then that's the same thing. Clarification needed.

Comment: @Enrique Sorry yes <= 0.

Comment: @Spacedman first time => going through Date from min(Date to max(Dat) so to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), `order` by 'Name', 'Date, grouped by 'Name' and specifying the logical condition (`Value <=0` in 'i', get the first row (`head(.SD, 1)`) and finally the set the column order as that of original dataset with `setcolorder`

```
library(data.table)
setcolorder(setDT(df1)[order(Name, Date)][Value <=0, head(.SD, 1), Name], names(df1))[]
#         Date Value    Name
#1: 2017-01-01     0 BlueCar
#2: 2017-01-02     0  RedCar
```

---

Or a `base R` only solution

```
df1[with(df1, tapply(seq_along(Value) *(Value <= 0), Name,
          FUN = function(x) x[x!=0][1]) ),]
#        Date Value    Name
#1 2017-01-01     0 BlueCar
#6 2017-01-02     0  RedCar
```

Comment: More haste less speed please.

Comment: @docendodiscimus  I pick data.table solution and if the OP has no other option in installing packages, an alternative to `duplicated` (which also needs to be `order`ed) is `tapply`

Comment: Tried it, but isn't robust against unordered Date column :-X

Comment: @bnassler That was not in the original question about unordered 'Date'

Comment: @bnassler  Updated the data.table solution to consider the 'Date' order

Comment: @akrun: Thanks, also for adapting the answer. data.table is awesome, but can you explain a little bit the steps you took?

Answer (score 1):

Find all the zero values, then take the first of each name by using `!duplicated`:

```
> d0 = data[data$Value<=0,]
> d0[!duplicated(d0$Name),]
        Date Value    Name
1 2017-01-01     0 BlueCar
6 2017-01-02     0  RedCar
```

Uses only base packages and not dplyr, data table or anything else.

Comment: `duplicated` probably always picks the first item right? In that case, this solution assumes that the data is sorted according to time. In the OP's example this seems to be the case, but wanted to add the caveat.

Comment: Ah, OP is ambiguous as to whether "first time" means "first in record order" or "with the earliest 'time' value"... *sigh*

Comment: #stackoverflowlife

Answer (score 1):

The following solution uses `dplyr`:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(Value <= 0) %>% top_n(1, Date)
```

where `group_by` obviously splits up the data by groups, and `top_n` get's back the first element. In your case you need this to be `Date` probably.

Comment: @spacedman Added testing for `<= 0`. In this case, the OP did not provide an easily pastable dataset (I know, `read.csv(text = )`, but I'm lazy :)), so in that case I often use another dataset.