# How to find the row where multiple columns are minimum

Tags: sql, sql-server

Very similar question to [Find Row where two columns are minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207608/find-row-where-two-columns-are-minimum) but I'm in SQL and I don't know how to translate.

I have data that looks like this:

| ID | Date | Status1 | Status2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 1 | Happy | Raining |
| 2 | Jan 2 | Sad | Raining |
| 3 | Jan 5 | Happy | Raining |
| 4 | Jan 8 | Sad | Raining |
| 5 | Jan 10 | Sad | Sunny |
| 6 | Jan 11 | **Happy** | **Sunny** |
| 7 | Jan 16 | Happy | Raining |
| 8 | Jan 19 | Happy | Sunny |

I need to locate the first occurrence where two particular statuses co-exist, in the example above, I want Happy and Sunny, so I'd like to locate row 6.

Is the most efficient option to get a row number partitioned by both columns? Or is there a way I should be using Min()?

Something like:

```
SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Status1, Status2, ORDER BY Date ASC) AS "RN"
FROM table
WHERE RN = 1
```

Then, for extra credit, my table doesn't actually look like the above. It actually looks like this:

| ID | Date | Value | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 1 | Happy | 1 |
| 2 | Jan 2 | Sad | 1 |
| 3 | Jan 5 | Happy | 1 |
| 4 | Jan 8 | Sad | 1 |
| 5 | Jan 10 | Sunny | 2 |
| 6 | Jan 11 | Happy | 1 |
| 7 | Jan 16 | Raining | 2 |
| 8 | Jan 19 | Sunny | 2 |

I had actually manipulated the data to get to the first sample table, above. Is there a different, more efficient way I can get my same result (I still want row 6) but without re-arranging the data from table 2 into table 1 first?

Comment: Are your "dates" really `varchar` values like `'Jan 1'` and `'Jan 19'`? if so, `'Jan 5'` is **after** `'Jan 16'` and `'Apr 1'` is **before** `'Jan 19'`. That would be a strong indicator of why you aren't getting the results you expect.

Comment: No, they're datetime2 format. I was simplifying, but sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: Also `ORDER BY Status 1, Status 2` is going to error as the column names aren't delimit identified.

Comment: I'm confused as to how in the first example there is a Happy and a Sunny both on Jan 11, but in the second example, you selected a row with only Happy.  Is the idea that since there is a Sunny on Jan 10, it is "still" Sunny for type 2?

Comment: @Cargo23, yes that's correct. It's still "Sunny"

Comment: Why not just use select top 1 from table1 where status1 = x and status2=y order by Date asc (assuming date is in fact a datetime)

Comment: OMG @bluedot I hadn't even thought of that. Need more coffee!